# return the index where the hash value is equal to

Tags: ruby

As the question asks I'm attempting to return the index where the value of the hash is equal to:

```
PRODUCT_DISCOUNT_TIERS = [
  {
    product_selector_match_type: :include,
    product_selector_type: :tag,
    product_selectors: ["Test Custom Hats"],
    tiers: "test tiers"
  },
  {
    product_selector_match_type: :include,
    product_selector_type: :tag,
    product_selectors: ["Bulk Discount Hat"],
    tiers: "test tiers"
  },
  {
    product_selector_match_type: :include,
    product_selector_type: :tag,
    product_selectors: ["Bulk Discount Blah"],
    tiers: "test tiers"
  },
  {
    product_selector_match_type: :include,
    product_selector_type: :type,
    product_selectors: ["Foo Blah Hats"],
    tiers: "test tiers"
  },
]
```

Here I want the index where "Foo Blah Hats" is:
My attempt is:

```
 getindx = PRODUCT_DISCOUNT_TIERS.find_index { |w| w[:product_selectors] == "Foo Blah Hats"}

print getindx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your hash stores `["Foo Blah Hats"]` and you're searching for `"Foo Blah Hats"`.

You may want to check if `"Foo Blah Hats"` is *included* in that array:

```
getindx = PRODUCT_DISCOUNT_TIERS.find_index { |w| 
  w[:product_selectors].include? "Foo Blah Hats"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
def find_index_of_hash_value(hash_array, value)
  hash_array.each_with_index do |hash, index|
    if hash.values.include?(value)
      return index
    end
  end
end
```